# AndroidStudio: FileNotFoundException при сборке проекта

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Во время сборки android-приложения появляется такая ошибка

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/AProject/android/assets/textures/mobs/boss (Это каталог)
```

Как решить эту проблему?
Сам путь существует.
При переименовании директории `boss` ошибка пропадает.

UPD: Проект разделён на модули, исходный код приложения в модуле `core`. Класс запуска на Android в модуле `android`. В каждом модуле своя `src` директория.

Comment: AProject должна находиться в том же месте, что и ваша src папка

Comment: @m0d, UPD: Проект разделён на модули, исходный код приложения в модуле `core`. Класс запуска на Android в модуле `android`. В каждом модуле своя `src` директория.

Answer (score 0):

Удалите .gradle и перезапустите студию.

Попробуйте удалить `AProject/.gradle/2.XX.X/taskArtifacts` далее перезапуск студии и перекомпилируйте проект.

Попробуйте удалить папку проекта и потом перезапустите с последующим восстановлением файлов/папок, если не поможет предыдущий вариант.

> Сделайте резервную копию на всякий случай.
>   AProject должна находиться в том же месте, что и ваша src папка